# SQL Server rollback transaction

Tags: sql-server, rollback

Will the `ROLLBACK` command drop a temporary table which is created during the transaction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will also roll back all work that has been done on that temp table before it is dropped. You can prevent this by creating the temp table before the transaction is created, or use a table variable which is not affected by the transaction.